# Display content from a URL (SQL Report) using HTML

Tags: html, ssms

Newbie here, been years and years since I wrote anything!  Struggling with the most simple thing!

I want to display the contents of a URL using HTML.

Goal:  I have a odd SQL report on a closed network that refuses to refresh.  I would like to use the HTML meta refresh option (works GREAT).

Problem:  If I use a  it stretches my SQL report table.  I need this report to display on one page, and it fits GREAT when displayed from SSMS.  But the second I add the report URL to my baby little HTML with the meta refresh and the iframe the report table is all stretched out.

Debugging:  I've played with the height (% to pixels), nothing seems to work.  Oddly the Width is never an issue, always display perfectly.  If I don't add the width/height attributes the report displays in a tiny box (2"x2"), but doesn't stretch the table.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post some html code you have been trying? That'll help us pinpoint the issue faster. Thanks.

Comment: are you setting height and width of iframe as in link -https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_width.asp